# Warning on Blogs embedded comments plugins is operating in compatibility mode, suggesting specifying an explicit 'href'

Tags: facebook, plugins, warnings, comments

Some days ago my blog's FB comment box plugin started showing a yellow coloured box beneath the comment writing form, showing the message:

> Warning: this comments plugin is operating in compatibility mode, but
>   has no posts yet. Consider specifying an explicit 'href' as suggested
>   in the comments plugin documentation to take advantage of all plugin
>   features.

I changed the value from URL to HREF but this way all URL formatted comments are hidden and not visible anymore, although they still remain in memory and they're visible again just changing again the code.

Is there a way to change the code to fit the new requirements, but keeping all the old comments visible?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a complete tutorial with a small use of JS to solve this issue.
**Visit the [tutorial](https://www.facebook.com/gil.goldshlager.dev?v=app_190322544333196).**

---

What I did was:

- Set off the parse for XFBML tags in the JS SDK
- Adding a function-call to the JS SDK with a date parameter that you manually set it once with a date that posts published after that date will start using the 'href' version, and posts published until that date will use the migrated version.
- Adding another attribute to the fb:comments tag which is 'data-date' and in it's value you place your post date (dynamic code).
- Calculating the dates in a JS code, and base on the result it's removing the not wanted attributes, and finally then it's render the XFBML tags using [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Comment: Using URL shortners are generally frowned upon, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup) for more info.

Comment: OK cool so now I know why my answers get deleted all the time, thanks I will not use URL shortners here any more from now and will edit all my published answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue in one site, but my requirement was different. I wanted to load comment box for each image in a gallery. When we click on an image it will start a slide show, and each image's comment will show on side panel like facebook and g+ did.

Here is the code I gone through: http://codekiku.blogspot.in/2012/03/facebook-comment-box-href-versions.html#!http://codekiku.blogspot.com/2012/03/facebook-comment-box-href-versions.html

```
var fbUrl="http://" + "www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=" +encodeURIComponent(URL);

fbTag = $('<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:400px" height="400px" width="300px" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
$(fbTag).attr('src',fbUrl);   
$("#newfb").html(fbTag); // a div which will load the comment box
if(FB==null){
 window.fbAsyncInit = function (){
  FB.init({
   appId: 'xxxxxxxx',// your app id
   status: true, // check login status
   cookie: true, /*
   enable cookies to allow the server
   to access the session*/
   xfbml: false  // parse XFBML
  });
 }
}
else{
 FB.init({
  appId: 'xxxxxxx',
  status: true, // check login status
  cookie: true, /*
  enable cookies to allow the server
  to access the session*/
  xfbml: false  // parse XFBML
 });
}
```